# FQL substitute for an SQL JOIN when I need related data from both joined tables?

Tags: facebook-fql, status

I am trying to get a list of friends who have liked any of a user's statuses in the past. I have a multiquery below that will do this, but the results are not grouped by post. So, I get a list of all friends who have liked the posts, but I don't know which friends liked which posts. I know I can run a separate call for each status, but I would like to do this in one call if possible. Any ideas?

```
$queries = '{
    "statuses":"SELECT status_id FROM status WHERE uid=me()",
    "likes":"SELECT user_id FROM like where object_id IN ( SELECT status_id FROM #statuses )",
    "liker":"SELECT name, pic_small FROM user WHERE uid IN (SELECT user_id FROM #likes)"
}';
$param = array(
    'method' => 'fql.multiquery',       
    'queries' => $queries,       
    'callback' => '');       
$queryresults = $facebook->api($param);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would've thought that you could just do:

```
$queries = '{
    "statuses":"SELECT status_id FROM status WHERE uid=me()",
    "likes":"SELECT user_id, object_id FROM like where object_id IN ( SELECT status_id FROM #statuses )",
    "liker":"SELECT name, pic_small, uid FROM user WHERE uid IN (SELECT user_id FROM #likes)"
}';
```

Then on your end you'll have all the information you need to map each `status_id` to an array of `name`s. It's not as clean or as trivial as doing an SQL JOIN, but since that's not an option this is the best you can do if you want to get all the data in one FQL call.

Comment: Brilliant. Sometimes the answer is directly in front of you and you can't see it. Thanks for the help.